# Formating the text within an EditText box after the user has finished

Tags: java, android

I would like to change the contents of an EditText box after the user has finished. So say if the user has entered a line of numbers such as 50126057, after he/she has finished I need some characters added to it before or after the user clicks the send button on my application. It needs to look like this: scn|50126057{) so that my application on the PC will understand it. Is there anyway this can be done?

Thanks and any help is much appreciated

P.S Sorry for spelling/grammar

Comment: Assuming that you read character's from the `EditBox` and then send it to PC app via some channel when user clicks send button.. Why cant you add the prefix and suffix before sending the data to the pc?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While clicking on Button event,

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){
String data="scn|"+edt.getText().toString()+"{)";
}
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, I feel so silly now that i realize it's such a simple bit of code. Thanks

Comment: If it correct answer click the right mark in your left side :)

Answer (score 0):

EditText word = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);

//inside button click event
//assign the word entered in the edit text to a string variable(in this case 'wordtoformat')

```
String wordtoformat=word.getText().toString();
```

//Now format the word as you want

```
wordtoformat="scn|"+wordtoformat+"{)";
```

//now assign the formated string back to the edit text

```
word.setText(text);
```

Hope it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OnFocus listener, something like this:

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(*editText id*);
et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(!hasFocus) {
        String text = et.getText().ToString();
        String newText = "scn|"+text+"{)";
        et.setText(newText);
    }
});
```

Sorry if I am not 100% accurate, but I've answered from work I've got no Android IDE here :)

Hope it helps you!

PS: The user is going to see the modified text only if he loses the focus of the EditText and then clicking the button or if by clicking the button the user won't leave the activity. But for the purpose of modifying the text, should work fine.